# How to covert IWICBitmapSource to HBITMAP?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wic

It's easy to produce IWICBitmap from HBITMAP with `CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP` factory method. But how to get simple GDI bitmap from IWICBitmapSource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortulately there is no way to convert a `IWICBitmap` to a `HBITMAP`, or to get one from a `IWICBitmapSource`. You could, however, easily create the `HBITMAP` from a pixel buffer if the format is compatible with what `CreateBitmap` expects.

Assuming a 32-bit RGBA bitmap:

```
IWICBitmapSource *bitmap_source = some_func();

UINT width = 0, height = 0;
bitmap_source->GetSize(&width, &height);

std::vector<BYTE> buffer(width * height * 4);
bitmap_source->CopyPixels(0, width * 4, buffer.size(), buffer.data());

HBITMAP bitmap = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 32, buffer.data());
```

Comment: Can you please improve your answer by adding the conversion with `WICConvertBitmapSource` to `32bppPBGRA` format before CopyPixels? It is native for GDI bitmaps as I can see from my test application

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that behind the scenes `IWICBitmapSource` even uses a GDI bitmap. You can access the raw bits using the `IWICBitmap::Lock` method, but if you want to use the bitmap with GDI functions I think you will need to create a GDI bitmap and copy the bits to it yourself.

Comment: Is there some library to do this automatically for all possible pixel formats of IWICBitmapSource?

Comment: GDI+ is probably your best bet.

Comment: Use WICConvertBitmapSource http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719819.aspx to convert the image data to a format GDI32 can handle, probably 32bppBGR or PBGRA.

Comment: @VincentPovirk Can you add your comment as answer? I'll check it as accepted, it's the most simple solution before `CopyPixels`