# How to acquire GDI compatible bitmap from windcodecs api IWICBitmapDecoder, IWICBitmap, or IWICImagingFactory?

Tags: winapi, rust, gdi

This post is the continuation of the problem I mentioned in [How to acquire instance of IWICImagingFactory in winapi-rs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68872506/#68883534), and initially described in [How to pass a reference to a buffer as a pointer of type [sometype;1] in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68795998/).

Now that I have found a way to use COM API to do error prone parsing of BMP files stored within the executable, I try to use them with winGDI (particularly `SelectObject()` and `DeleteObject()`) which require an `HGDIOBJECT` type.

The search for the conversion to a GDI-compatible bitmap eventually left me with something like this:

```rust
    let mut pFactory: *mut c_void = zeroed();
    let hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_WICImagingFactory as *const IID,
                              null_mut(),
                              CLSCTX_INPROC,
                              &IWICImagingFactory::uuidof(),
                              &mut pFactory as *mut *mut c_void);
                        
    
    let mut pBmp: *mut IWICBitmap = zeroed();
    
    let hr = (pFactory as *mut _ as *mut IWICImagingFactory)
                             .as_ref()
                             .unwrap()
                             .CreateBitmapFromMemory(
                                 size.cx as u32,
                                 size.cy as u32,
                                 &GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppRGB,
                                 (buffer.len() as u32 / size.cy as u32),
                                 buffer.len() as u32,
                                 buffer.as_ptr(),
                                 &mut pBmp as *mut *mut IWICBitmap
                             );
```

As I've abandoned the idea to use `IStream` and `CreateDecoderFromStream()` due to seemingly no-what-so-ever functionality allowing me to obtain a GDI-compatible bitmap from `IWICBitmapDecoder`.

I'm not positive such functionality is implemented for `IWICBitmap` either, but casting it to `HGDIOBJECT` and sequentially using in `SelectObject()` doesn't cause an error, however it doesn't produce the image.

Is the only solution to instantiate new bitmaps and copy the pixel data and bitmap info?

Comment: There's nothing built-in as far as I know, you need to use `CreateDIBSection` to create a GDI bitmap and then call the `CopyPixels` method on the `IWICBitmap` to copy the image data over.

Comment: `IWICBitmap` is a COM interface, whereas `HGDIOBJECT`/`HBITMAP` is a handle to a kernel object.  You can't simply type-cast between them, even if it compiles (and that is only because `HGDIOBJECT`/`HBITMAP` are `void*`, which ALL pointers are convertible to). They are not the same thing, and thus are not interchangable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to covert IWICBitmapSource to HBITMAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602548/how-to-covert-iwicbitmapsource-to-hbitmap)

Comment: That's possible, sure, but it's a lot of work. You need to get an `IWICBitmapDecoder` from the image data, call `GetFrame` to get an `IWICBitmapSource`, construct an `IWICFormatConverter` and feed the bitmap source into it. Now you need to `CreateDIBSection`, and `CopyPixels` the pixel data over. Lots of decisions to make and lots of opportunities to make the wrong decisions. Linking an image resource into an executable and calling `LoadImage` is just way simpler, even [with Rust](https://crates.io/crates/embed-resource).